# sIFR: visible on local, not remote

Tags: view, sifr, local

When working on a static mirror of the site, the sIFR is rendered correctly using Dreamweaver's live view. When viewing site locally in a browser, the regular text is printed, as expected. However, when uploaded and viewed from a remote web server, neither is visible.

I am using version 3 of sIFR, and the site can be viewed here, with an example page employing siFR implementation:
http://www.thevulgarbulgar.com/TEMP/rush/vacancies.html

Whereas it should look like so:

rush.co.uk/vacancies

Thanks for looking.

vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash movie can't be found: http://www.thevulgarbulgar.com/sites/all/themes/basic/flash/futuraxb.swf

Answer (score 0):

ahh, tis looking from root, when file is here: http://www.thevulgarbulgar.com/TEMP/rush/sites/all/themes/basic/flash/futuraxb.swf

Thanks.